# running 20.04.1 server but missing netplan config files

Tags: networking, server

I added a 2nd NIC to my Ubuntu 20.04.1 server VM (ESXi). I went into /etc/netplan/ to edit the config file to give that NIC a static IP address and discovered the directory was empty. I've performed several in-place upgrades (do-release-upgrade, or equivalent) for this Ubuntu server installation over the years, starting from 10.x or 12.x, I think. I'm guessing something got messed up along the way...? The 1st NIC already has a static IP address which carried over from the previous installations. How do I configure network settings if there's no netplan config?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Not sure if this is the proper way, but I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and gave the second NIC a static IP address. However, running `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` did not work, so I had to restart the VM for the change to go into effect.

It looks like this method of managing interfaces is from Ubuntu 16.04.

Hope that helped someone out there.